# Error in php code indentation

Tags: php

I am working in code indentation in php, while i was working on following code snippet its showing following error

```
<? php
$name = 'Alex';
$age = 21;
if (strtolower($name)) 
    {
    if ($age>=21) 
        {
        echo "You are not over 21";
        if (1===1) 
        {
            echo "yes, 1 is equal to 1";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "You are not Alex";
    }
}
?>
```

=21) { echo "You are not over 21"; if (1===1) { echo "yes, 1 is equal to 1"; } } else { echo "You are not Alex"; } } ?>

what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: And what is that error it's showing....? Also, `if (strtolower($name))` should be `if (strtolower($name) == "alex")` right?

Comment: You print: *You are NOT over 21* when the have is equal or bigger than 21..

Comment: Every `if` is true here. Why the `else` then?

Comment: You have `<? php` at the start of your file. Remove the space like `<?php` and check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing PHP code output to your webpage, the code isn't being recognised as PHP on your web server and therefore is being treated as html. Change `<?` php  to `<?php`. `<?` would only work if php short tags are turned on and thus the following "php" would throw a PHP error.

Comment: How is this anywhere related with the question ?

Comment: @cbf worked perfectly.